# How can I kill or refresh Desktop Wallpaper with a Terminal command?

Tags: terminal, command-line, display, settings

Is there a command for refreshing the Display Settings? Or, in specific, refreshing the Desktop Wallpaper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try restarting `dock` which, amongst many things, draws the wallpaper on the desktop. But be careful; as `dock` also controls a lot of window management apps may 'un-minimise' or un-hide and windows. As `dock` also controls Mission Control, you won't be able to change spaces or go into Mission Control until `dock` restarts again (which is mostly instantly).

From terminal, try:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: Thanks; didn't think it would do the trick -- but it did.

Comment: Any idea how to refresh the Login wallpaper?